# c# Flappybird "Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method"

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to re-create flappybird in Visual studio 2015 c# for a little school project. But for some reason i get this error that i really can't fix. I'm following an tutorial on how to create flappybird, but the one making the tutorial is writing in VB.net Heres the YT Link and under that my code I'm trying to make.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnjdMbdEzMo

```
public partial class Form10 : Form
{

    int gravity = 1;
    int yspeed = 0;
    PictureBox[,] Pipe;

    public Form10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        this.yspeed += this.gravity;
        bird.Top += this.yspeed;            
    }
    private void inGameKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            this.yspeed = -15;
        }
    }
    private void pausePlayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gameTimer.Enabled == true)
        {
            gameTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (gameTimer.Enabled == false)
            {
                gameTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private void restartToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void startGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gameTimer.Enabled == false)
        {
            gameTimer.Enabled = true;
            startGame.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void CreatePipes(int number)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; (i <= number); i++)
        {
            var temp = new PictureBox();
            this.Controls.Add(temp);
            temp.Width = 50;
            temp.Height = 370;
            temp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            temp.BackColor = Color.Red;
            temp.Top = 50;
            temp.Left = (2 * 200) + 300;
            Pipe(i) = temp;
            Pipe(i).Visable = true; 
        }
    }
    private void Form10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gameTimer.Enabled = true;
        CreatePipes(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: Probably at `Pipe(i)`. `Pipe` is a two-dimensional array, so it should be something like `Pipe[x,y]`, where `x` and `y` depend on the dimensions, but I can't see where you intialize `Pipe`.

Comment: You're mixing VB.NET and C# syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is in the lines

```
Pipe(i) = temp;
Pipe(i).Visable = true;
```

If you are trying to access Pipe as an array, the syntax is `Pipe[i]`, although pipe is a 2d array so it should be `Pipe[i,j]` Where j is something else.

Also you have misspelled Visible.

Comment: Yea i know the visible is misspelled xD I kinda tried to see if it would auto correct it as normal. But As it did not recognize "Pipe(i)" it could not auto correct it. Thanks for your help. I've tried to apply the fix and it worked. Now i just need to use "j" for something :)

Comment: @Minik, Good, happy coding.